# Access common value in call back in strict mode

Tags: javascript, strict

I have accessed common value in call back like this.

```
function InfoClass() {
    var local = 1;
    self = this;
}
InfoClass.prototype.myFunction = function (){
    this.win.addEventListener('open', function(e){
          // I can't use 'this' here. 
        self.local // So I access common value in callback like this.
    });
}
```

Before strict mode it works,

However ,now I need to set strict mode, so it shows error `self` doesn't have `var`.

Is there any alternative way??

Comment: Just use an arrow function instead so that you inherit the `this` of the parent scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```
InfoClass.prototype.myFunction = function (){
    var self = this;
    this.win.addEventListener('open', function(e){
        self.local // you can access the function now
    });
}
```

Or you can use arrow function like following

```
InfoClass.prototype.myFunction = function (){
    this.win.addEventListener("open", (e) => {
         this.local // you can use this now
    });
}
```

For reference, [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Oh,later one looks really cool for me , I will learn more. thanks very mcuh